# Cannot update svg file(s) for saleor framework + python + django

Tags: django, python-3.x, saleor

I would like to know how should i could manage to change the **static** files use by the *saelor framework*. I've tried to change the logo.svg but failed to do so.

I'm still learning python program while using the saleor framework for e-commerce.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post what you tried and exact code you tried to modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it should be done. You must put your logo in the `saleor/static/images` folder then change it in `base.html` file in `footer` and `navbar` section.